# Is it possible to use a URL to extract values from the pdf instead of using the pdf file for the below code?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Is it possible to use a URL to extract values from the PDF instead of using the PDF file for the below code?

```
file = "abc.pdf"

layout, dim = camelot.utils.get_page_layout(file)

print(dim)
```

What I am trying to achieve is, instead of having `<file = "abc.pdf">`, to have `<file = "http://........pdf">`.

Comment: do you mean is it possible to read the PDF from a url rather than from a local file on the file system?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle No, what i mean is like.. as per the above code i have to specify the name of the pdf file i am working with, but what i need is instead of using the pdf file name, can i use a url where the pdf is uploaded?